# vim 8.1 send_termkeys problem

Tags: terminal-buffer

I noticed that, if I use

```
call term_sendkeys(buf, "make\n")
```

and then I try to execute something else in the terminal windows (i.e. `ls`), vim append the last string sent from command mode to the actual string just inserted in the terminal window.

Resuming, if I execute (from command mode)

```
call term_sendkeys(buf, "make\n")
```

and then, from the terminal window I execute `ls` , the inner shell automaticallt executes

```
lsmake
```

Is this a bug or what am I missing here ?

Comment: Try following this solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318522/send-buffer-to-a-running-terminal-window-in-vim-8 I suspect your "\n". Not sure.

Comment: What happens if you use "\<cr>" instead of "\n"?